# JSON is failing after adding an HTML link to this string (PHP included too)

Tags: php, json

So I am using mandrill to send email, and this here works:

```
"html" : "Hi '.$fullName.', <br><br> Welcome to BlaBla ! We\'re glad to have you on board. <br><br> Please visit this link to confirm your email address:<br> http://www.BlaBla.com/verifyEmail.php?email='.$email.'&token='.$token.'<br><br> If you need any help, please do not hesitate to reply to this email and we will get in touch shortly. <br> <br> Thank you, <br> The BlaBla Crew",
```

but this fails to send the email:

```
"html" : "Hi '.$fullName.', <br><br> Welcome to BlaBla ! We\'re glad to have you on board. <br><br> Please visit this link to confirm your email address:<br> <a href="blabla.com">http://www.BlaBla.com/verifyEmail.php?email='.$email.'&token='.$token.'</a><br><br> If you need any help, please do not hesitate to reply to this email and we will get in touch shortly. <br> <br> Thank you, <br> The BlaBla Crew",
```

Been a puzzle for an hour. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rewrite it as follows. You haven't escaped the `"`

```
"html" : "Hi '.$fullName.', <br><br> Welcome to BlaBla ! We\'re glad to have you on board. <br><br> Please visit this link to confirm your email address:<br> <a href=\"blabla.com\">http://www.BlaBla .com/verifyEmail.php?email='.$email.'&token='.$token.'</a><br><br> If you need any help, please do not hesitate to reply to this email and we will get in touch shortly. <br> <br> Thank you, <br> The BlaBla Crew",
```

Comment: Thank you... Sublime Text's syntax highlighting didn't change so I didn't even think of trying it, godammit!!! Thanks :)